# HDD EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT both EFI\MICROSOFT\RECOVERY empty

Tags: windows, boot, bios, format, efi

Hi i accidently formated some parts of partisions on my laptop. Now when it stats it's just a blank blue screen , not that basic with that sad face , but really empty blue screen. I dont know how to fix it. Watched ton of videos and read ton of forums but i couldn't  find the answer. I believe with your help i can somehow fix it. When i go to my settings after F2 , my boot option priorities are empty. (If i dont count usb that i had plugged in.) If i add new boot option and go to "Path for boot option" and choose my "HDD SATA 256 MB" and go to  then  i can choose out of  and . I opened both of them many times but they're empty and i can only take a step back. When i boot from my usb nothing happenes. Only place where i can get is the blank blue screen. I cannot get to command prompt or others options on windows help screen. Please tell me it can still be fixable :(

Comment: Probably not fixable. You need to rebuild the partitions with the Windows ISO Installer.

Comment: What did you format? We can only guess. But John is probably right too: you've stopped it part of your OS and you have to reinstall to fix that.

Comment: 1. Try to salvage any data by booting from a rescue disk. 2. Then reinstall Windows from ISO,